# Subscription to specific products

Tags: 6, ubercart

I'm using [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) module. I want to organize a subscription to a certain type of products in my site. I've tried the [uc_recurring](http://drupal.org/project/uc_recurring) module, but it offers subscription to the orders only, and i'm going to make it possible to choose a custom period(recurring) for every product in the cart.

How can I make this issue work?

Comment: You don't mention which version of neither übercart nor drupal you are using.

Comment: Hi there, it's drupal 6 and ubercart 6.x-2.7

Comment: Hi :) I don't use Übercart myself, but I figured it would be important to someone that actually does to know.

Comment: Yeap, i'm searching the stack and google there are lots of this kind of issues but i can't figure out on my situation